# Como tratar um reponse.result.value que retorna como log optional([])?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-3, alamofire

Estou na seguinte situação tenho um requisição no Alamofire que me retorna um json que pode ter dados ou não(geralmente tem mas pode ser que não). Eu quero tratar quando o response.result.value retorna optional([]).

Tentei isso mas não deu certo

```
   let json = response.result.value
   print(json)//retorna Optional[]

   if json == nil {
      //aviso o usuario que nao tenho os dados pra mostrar
   }
   else{
      //trabalho com os dados retornados
      if let json = json {
         for JSON in json {     
            //for para percorrer o objeto que me foi retornado
      }
   }
```

Comment: Só uma coisa, esse 'json == nil' não precisa, já que ali em baixo tu faz if 'let json = json'. O if let já faz a verificação se é diferente de nil e tira o optional dele

Comment: Não funciona pois eu nunca vou ter um nil pois quando não a nada no json ele me da um []. Ai o nil não funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Eu encontrei a solução para meu problema não sei se é a maneira correta mas funcionou.

```
    let json = response.result.value
       print(json?.toJSONString())//retorna Optional("[]")

       if json?.toJSONString() != "[]" {
          //trabalho com os dados retornados
          if let json = json {
             for JSON in json {     
                //for para percorrer o objeto que me foi retornado
          }
       }
       else{
          //aviso o usuario que nao tenho os dados pra mostrar
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Caro colega,

No Swift a forma para fazer toda a validação de uma varável opcional é usando o if let, conforme demonstrado abaixo. Essa verificação substitui o if que você fez.

```
if let result = response.result.value{
    //faz o que voce quer aqui
}else{
    //aviso o usuario que nao tenho os dados pra mostrar
}
```

Se o valor não for nulo ele cai no if normalmente atribuindo o valor do response.result.value a constante result (nesse caso vai funcionar como uma variável local) e se o resultado for nulo cai no else.

Answer (score 0):

É só tratar como você trataria um response que retorna um array de objetos e verificar se ele está vazio.

```
//mockando o optional([])
let json: [Any]? = [Any]() 
if let array = json as? [[String: Any]] {
    if array.isEmpty {
        print("Não há dados para exibir")
    }
}

//mockando array de objetos
let data = "[{\"id\":1},{\"id\":2}]".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! 
let json2 = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
if let array = json2 as? [[String: Any]] {
    if array.isEmpty {
        print("Não há dados para exibir")
    } else {
        print(array)
    }
}

//resultado:
// - Não há dados para exibir
// - [["id": 1], ["id": 2]]
```